# Magento 2 - Auto select option if only one is awailable

Tags: magento2

I want to achieve, that if configurable product has only one option (swatch or option in dropdown), to auto select that option. Can you help me please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$(document).on('swatch.initialized', function() {
var swatchLength = $('.swatch-attribute.color').length;
var onlyOneColor = $('.swatch-attribute.color .swatch-option').length;
    if(swatchLength == 1 && onlyOneColor == 1){
        $('.swatch-option').first().trigger('click');
    }
});
```